# How to pass className styles to react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

Whenever I try to pass down styles to my `Table` component through the `className` prop it breaks and doesn't render either the default styles or the styles passed down. If I do not pass styles down through the `className` prop, the `Table`'s default styles will show up fine. I have tried joining the strings with interpolation and concatenation with no success. The `.join('')` method works for multiple styles if the styles are not passed down from another component.

My Table Component

```tsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Table.module.scss';

const Table = ({ 
  children,
  className 
}: { 
  children: React.ReactNode; 
  className?: string 
}) => {
  return <table className={[styles.table, className].join('')}>{children}</table>;
};
```

The Parent Component

```tsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './PaymentTable.module.scss';
import Table '../Table';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const PaymentTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Table className={styles.paymentTable}>
      {children}
    </Table>
  );
};
export default PaymentTable;
```

The Table Sass File

```scss
@use 'shared/styles';

.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;

  caption,
  th,
  td {
    font-size: styles.em(14);
    line-height: styles.em(17);
  }

  caption,
  th {
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  caption {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  th,
  td {
    text-align: center;
  }

  th {
    background-color: styles.color(gray, 95);
    padding: 8px 0px;
  }

  th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  }

  th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  }

  td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid styles.color(gray, 95);
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 18px 0px;
  }

  tr td:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid styles.color(gray, 95);
  }

  tr td:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid styles.color(gray, 95);
  }

  tr:last-child {
    td:first-child {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    }

    td:last-child {
      border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    }
  }
}
```

The Payment Table Sass File

```scss
.paymentTable {
  tbody tr {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you trying using `join(' ')`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yeah I was missing a space. DOH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple class names into the className prop in a single string.

Parent:

```
const PaymentTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Table className="paymentTable">
      {children}
    </Table>
  );
};
```

Child:

```
  children,
  className 
}: { 
  children: React.ReactNode; 
  className?: string 
}) => {
  return <table className=`${styles.table} ${className}`>{children}</table>;
};
```

Also you are joining classNames with no spaces `.join('')`. If you want to stick to your methodology, you'll need to split them with `.join(' ')`